# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard--Warning, silence possible?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

> "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard
>   iPhone-LandscapeChoco-NumberPad; using
>   76885345_LandscapeChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default"

I'm getting this output in Debugger when using a `UITextField` with Keyboard Type as `Number Pad`.

All searchings seem to say that the warning is benign and can be ignored.

---

Is it possible to silence this warning by preemptively setting `UITextField` to use Keyboard `76885345_LandscapeChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default` that will be used eventually?